# Comms in Model View Controller Framework

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm trying out the Model View Controller Pattern in a test C# project. In my project I want to be able to receive messages that will affect the model, and send a message over a socket when a Model is changed in a certain way. I also want to be have the user send messages from the UI ( view ). What should handling the sending and receiving ? I think it should go in the controller, which would change the model appropriately when receiving, and so the model or view would call on the controller to post a message, but the MVC pattern is a bit foreign to me so I'm not sure.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear here - are you looking to do this pattern in a winforms client (or wpf) or on the web?   ASP.Net MVC is just that - for MVC, although it doesn't mean you can't adapt this pattern to winform but the implementation now is for ASP.Net